# DevExpress Grid, Bool rows change not reflect immediatly

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, devexpress

I have a DX grid view and it has 2 bool columns. My purpose is when I check for ex 2nd row in column1, column2 2nd must be changed immediatly, but not. It changes after clicking another row. Here is my rowcellvaluechanged event code :

```
 void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //button1.PerformClick();
        if (e.Column.Name == "col1")
        {
             var x = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandler, col1);
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandler, col2, x);
        }

    }
```

I looked for in DX website and there is no solution. How can I handle on it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GridView.PostEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_PostEditortopic) method to immediately pass the changed value from the editor into the Grid's underlying data source. The best place for doing this is the [EditValueChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItem_EditValueChangedtopic) event of real cell editor. You can handle this event as follows:

```
gridView1.PopulateColumns();
var checkEdit = gridView1.Columns["Value1"].RealColumnEdit as RepositoryItemCheckEdit;
checkEdit.EditValueChanged += checkEdit_EditValueChanged;
//...
void checkEdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    gridView1.PostEditor();
}
```

Then you can implement all needed dependencies:

```
gridView1.CellValueChanged += gridView1_CellValueChanged;
//...
void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Column.FieldName == "Value1") 
        gridView1.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gridView1.Columns["Value2"], e.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Grid posts an editor value when you switch to another cell. To force it, call the [PostEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_PostEditortopic) method. But, in this case, you will need to use the EditValueChanged event of the active editor. To get it, use the [ActiveEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ActiveEditortopic) property. To catch the moment, when an editor is created, use the [ShownEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShownEditortopic) event.

```
gridView1.ShownEditor += gridView1_ShownEditor;

private void gridView1_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GridView view = (GridView)sender;
    view.ActiveEditor.EditValueChanged += editor_EditValueChanged;
}

private void editor_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!gridView1.FocusedColumn.Name == "col1")
        return;
    gridView1.PostEditor();
    var x = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandler, col1);
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(e.RowHandler, col2, x);
}
```

Comment: A small correction: you need to unsubscribe the editor_EditValueChanged  event handler with using the [GridView.HiddenEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_HiddenEditortopic) event