# Updating Grid View Row after changing a Value, needs clicking - Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, radgridview

I have a populated Rad Grid View, there is a check box column in every row. If user checks it, the first cell's fore color will change.

Everything works fine, but there is a small problem.

After checking the check box, user should click somewhere to see its affect. I need after checking the check box, user Immediately sees changes into the first cell.

How is it possible?

Comment: which event do you use? can I see your code? I am not familiar with Telerik Btw

Comment: I use CellEndEdit and CellFormatting Events

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the control, as you say it takes effect only after a click is performed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924344/devexpress-grid-bool-rows-change-not-reflect-immediatly

check this question, I had similar issue and found soluition